# Are there any good PostgreSQL clients for linux?

Tags: linux, postgresql, client, database-administration

I am frustrated of not having a good Linux GUI administration and development tool for PostgreSQL.

pgAdmin III is buggy and unusable piece of... hmm, software, compared to Windows-only PostgreSQL Maestro and EMS PostgreSQL manager.

phpPgaAmin does not looks promising.

EMS PostgreSQL manager can work under Wine, but such setup have a number of issues.

Requirements are:

1. Table data editing and browsing for large tables (1M+), able to jump by FK or some master-slave editing, GUI filtering and so on.
2. ER diagrams with in-place schema editing
3. Schema editing and browsing with all useful GUI support
4. Schema changes log to put into DB versioning (migrations script).
5. Tabbed interface to be able to work with a number of tables and SQL queries at once.

And so on.

Any ideas?

Comment: @nemo - Is ServerFault out of private beta yet?

Comment: Which is "currently in private beta testing". Can't get in.

Comment: Which version of pgAdmin3 are you using? I find that the newer releases are much less buggy. Also, the beta key for server fault is on the stack overflow blog.

Comment: @Dana the Sane 1.8.4 The main problem with pgAdmin is mantra "at one time do things with one object". There are no tabs or something, multiple windows are limited. Navigating 200+ tables is painful.

Comment: Is this for a particular desktop environment? (Gnome, KDE, etc.)

Comment: This is on Server Fault too: http://serverfault.com/questions/11315/any-good-postgresql-client-for-linux. I guess this SO question should be closed now.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried Squirrel SQL?

http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/

Comment: All Java tools I see was, say, a little too abstracted from database and thus my particular needs.

Comment: Understandable. It's a very generic, technology-agnostic tool, so I can see where that could be an issue. Have you tried Postgres Studio?

Comment: No, but the screenshot for Postgres Studio looks exactly the same as pgAdmin III, with the only different window title.

Answer (score 5):

At the moment I suggest the use of DBeaver (http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/download/) that supports the Postgres and many other databases.

[2016 update]
Actually i'm using DataGrip https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/ is a tool developed by Intellij

Answer (score 2):

### Postgresql Tools

- [Phppgadmin](http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/) - I think you should reevaluate your outright dismissal of this tool. It has a larger feature set than PgAdmin III and allows you to connect over the local socket rather than strictly over the tcp port via JDBC.
- [Aqua Data Studio](http://www.aquafold.com/) - I used to use this tool quite often, but I'm unsure of its current status. It supports ER maps and has a number of features that are useful to developers.

I doubt you will find everything that you want in a single tool. I a lot of development using Postgresql and I still find myself the most efficent with a nice text editor and the command line psql tool.

Answer (score 0):

At the momen Navicat seems to produce the best admin tools for databases IMHO.

Check out their free version (premium supporting multiple databases including postgres or just postgres version: ...for postgresql)

http://navicat.com/en/download/download.html

Comment: So i made the mistake of actually purchasing navicat Linux version. it is basically Windows version wrapped in wine which is prone to crashes.