# Looking for free GUI tool to work with PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

Currently, I am using standalone GUI tool [DbSchema](http://www.dbschema.com/) to design my database schema.

I like it because it can

1. Generate SQL code.
2. Have graphing view on my entire database schema.

[image]
<sub>(source: [google.com](http://sites.google.com/site/yanchengcheok/Home/PostgreSQL.png))</sub>

However, I realize the SQL code generate by DbSchema is not being recognized by PostgreSQL.

```
CREATE TABLE lot (
    lot_id    serial AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    operator_name    text,
    machine_name    text,
    timestamp    timestamp,
    CONSTRAINT pk_lot_id PRIMARY KEY(lot_id)) 

CREATE TABLE unit (
    unit_id    serial AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    fk_lot_id    serial NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_unit_id PRIMARY KEY(unit_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_lot_id FOREIGN KEY( fk_lot_id ) REFERENCES lot ( lot_id ))
```

I get the error :

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "AUTO_INCREMENT"
```

Is there any alternative "just work" free tool that I can work with PostgreSQL, by providing above 2 features?

Comment: I assume that you are using Windows, but for Linux, visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898255/any-good-postgresql-client-for-linux

Comment: Since this is a paying product, you should ask their support about it. AUTO_INCREMENT is not supported by many DBMS, at least not by PostgreSQL, Oracle, or SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the [VisualUML/DBA](http://visualuml.com) kit. Its not free but it sure is nice. It'll do what you are asking for and it'll generate the DB (with your favorite DBMS) create/drop script for you.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what platform you are working you [have some options](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools):

- [PgAdmin III](http://www.pgadmin.org/)
- [DreamCoder for PostgreSQL Freeware (Windows)](http://www.sqldeveloper.net/download.html)
- [Druid III](http://druid.sourceforge.net/)
- [OpenOffice.Org](http://dba.openoffice.org/drivers/postgresql/index.html)(!)
- [PgAccess](http://www.pgaccess.org)
- [Squirrel SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Do you mean phppgadmin? No! I do not want web based tool. I am working on my standalone machine.

Comment: But after I go through the list of their web site, non of them has the "diagram layout" feature as here : http://www.dbschema.com/screenshots.html

Comment: Really? http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/screenshots/graph.png http://druid.sourceforge.net/#Features http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fIYtbdamzp8&feature=player_embedded http://dba.openoffice.org/drivers/postgresql/index.html#features

Comment: How does PgAdmin answer the OP's needs? (I'm not aware of a graphical way to see the schema in PgAdmin...)