# Looking for free(ish) PostgreSQL database viewer for Mac

Tags: postgresql, uml, viewer

Is there any software for viewing UML-like diagrams of postgreSQL DB schemas for the Mac?  Here's an example of what I would like to see.

[image]
<sub>(source: [google.com](http://sites.google.com/site/yanchengcheok/Home/PostgreSQL.png))</sub>

Cheap's good, free's better.

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978722/looking-for-free-gui-tool-to-work-with-postgresql), but the software pointed to here appears not to be available for the Mac, and is no longer being supported anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DbWrench is not free (but not expensive either) and quite good: http://www.dbwrench.com/

PowerArchitect Community edition is free, but the really interesting features seem to go into the enterprise edition: http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/architect

Both are Java based and work on the Mac

Answer (score 1):

Some days ago I had the same question.  I found several, but the one that I'm using is DbVisualizer.  It is multi-platform, free, and easy to install. It also has a paid version, but the free one is enough for visualization purposes. It supports PostgreSQL, MySQL, Informix, Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, and many other DBMS'.

Here is the [download link](http://www.dbvis.com/download/)

Answer (score 0):

[Aqua Data Studio](http://www.aquafold.com/postgresql_client.html) offers an ER diagram generator and ER modeler but it's pricey now.

Free licenses for [qualified](http://www.aquafold.com/opensourcedeveloper-qual.html) open source developers; reduced licenses for [qualified](http://www.aquafold.com/academic-qual.html) academic users.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer's link doesn't work any more.

Here is an acceptable tool that's free and produces graphic diagrams: http://www.dbvis.com/